# How to display single page of children with a view per page types in Silverstripe 3

Tags: single-page-application, silverstripe

I have a single page app that I can display all the children in my page.ss via

```
<% control children %>
```

However that will only ever output as 1 view via page.ss and I want to use individual views for every page type, all on a single page app design.

So my index page includes all content from children pages, but I want each children page to have its own view.

Is that possible in Silverstripe 3, and if so, how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use DataObjects instead of pages, as the other answer indicates (shameless plug for my [blocks-module](https://github.com/bummzack/page-blocks)).

If you prefer pages, that's also possible. It requires some trickery when it comes to templating, but works fairly well once set up.

#### The Home-Page

First of all, you need an entry-point for your page. This is usually the home-page. It'll need a separate template, therefore I suggest you create a special `HomePage` class for this.

Eg.

```
<?php
class HomePage extends Page
{
    // only allow one HomePage
    public function canCreate($member = null)
    {
        return parent::canCreate($member) 
            ? HomePage::get()->count() == 0
            : false;
    }
}

class HomePage_Controller extends Page_Controller
{

}
```

#### Special templates

Your home-page will render all other pages into one template. I've implemented this in a way that pages use a different template to render into the single-page view. Create a method like this in your `Page` class:

```
/**
 * Get markup for single-page layout
 * @return HTMLText
 */
public function getHTML()
{
    return $this->renderWith(array('Flat' . $this->ClassName, 'FlatPage'));
}
```

This setup expects the templates to be your class-name, prefixed with `Flat`. So if you have a `GalleryPage` class, it will use the `FlatGalleryPage` template. If the template isn't found, it will fall back to `FlatPage`. For clarity, you can create all these templates in a separate folder. Eg.

```
# Example folder structure
templates
  + SinglePage
      + FlatPage.ss
      + FlatGalleryPage.ss
      + …
```

With this setup, you can have different templates for the single-page output and "regular" output.

#### Combining the previous steps

In your `HomePage.ss` template, you can now render all pages like this:

```
<% loop $Menu(1) %>
    <section id="$URLSegment">
        $HTML
    </section>
<% end_loop %>
```

And your navigation might look like this:

```
<nav class="main">
    <ul>
    <% loop $Menu(1) %>
        <li>
            <a href="#/$URLSegment" >$MainMenuTitle</a>
        </li>
    <% end_loop %>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

This will just add an anchor-based navigation to navigate to the different pages. You are free to spice things up with some JavaScript.

#### Caveats and Tips

Forms in a single-page view are tricky, since you're viewing different pages via a single controller. Also response-rendering will be difficult. If you need forms within your single-page app, I suggest you use AJAX to keep the user within the current view.

If you want to prevent direct access to sub-pages, you could use a data-extension that redirects the user to the home-page. Example:

```
<?php

/**
 * Redirect to the home-page whenever somebody tries to access this page
 */
class RedirectToHomeExtension extends DataExtension
{
    public function contentcontrollerInit($controller)
    {
        // Check if the current user isn't somebody with CMS access,
        // since this would mess with the CMS preview-pane.
        if (!(
            Permission::check('CMS_ACCESS_CMSMain', 'any') ||
            Permission::check('CMS_ACCESS_LeftAndMain', 'any')
        )){
            $controller->redirect(HomePage::get()->First()->Link(), 301);
        }
    }
}
```

Then apply it as usual via config:

```
GalleryPage:
  extensions:
    - RedirectToHomeExtension
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the code for the [StripeCon EU website](https://github.com/silverstripe-europe-meetup/website-2015)
It works with sections (which are actually pages). The sections are independently viewable, but at the homepage, it's a onepager.

I think that's what you're after?